# I cant found how to use json format in to my xamarin project

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Sorry guys. I am really newbie at programming. I must make a program with json format data. But i cant found how can i use it in my xamarin form or how to include my program.

[image: Its my json data.]

Its my json data. I paste it into https://json2csharp.com and used it.
But i dont know how can i use it. For example in a label i need take name info from that json data. Like i said im really newbie but i cant found any example in network or stackoverflow can u help me please ? Thank you all <3

Comment: there are **thousands** of examples out there - a quick search of "xamarin json" returns a lot of great hits.  If there is some **specific** step you don't understand, please post the code you have so far and ask about that **specific** problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow below steps:

1.install **Newtonsoft.Json** nuget package.

2.create a model class,for example:

```
public class MyInfor
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Barcode{ get; set; }
   ...  // define the variables which the name is same as the key in your json data
}
```

3.convert your json data to the model you defined.

```
string json = "your json string";
MyInfor myInfor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfor>(json);
label.Text = myInfor.Name;
```

Comment: Brother i love you so much i just get it with your comment thank you so much <3 IT HELPED  A LOT!